# Angular2 manipulate ngModel view

Tags: angular, ngmodel

I would like to manipulate ngModel view like you can do $formatter / $parser in Angular 1.

My original idea is to do the following

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="context.highQueuePriority" (ngModelChange)="appendPercent($event)" />
```

and with this function

```
appendPercent(val): string {
    this.context.highQueuePriority = val.replace(/^[a-zA-Z%]+/g, '') + '%';
}
```

to basically changes the view to 40% if user enters 40.

Comment: so what's the problem with this?

Comment: I have 3 same input that requires the same function. I just wanna see if there's a better way to do this. Also I need to manipulate the data when I first get it and manipulate it again when I send it back.

Answer (score 0):

I found a perfect article explaining how to do this. Posting it for anyone else that might come across it. https://blog.ngconsultant.io/custom-input-formatting-with-simple-directives-for-angular-2-ec792082976#.fp9qc9x9c